# What could have caused bridge rectifiers to fail?

Tags: bridge-rectifier

Ok, so I have a pioneer surround sound that I was trying to fix because of one speaker had very low volume. What I changed was a resistor, its the exact same color stripes, but the size is a bit bigger. When tested, the surround sound detected an error and went into protected mode. Until I forced reset it the 2 bridge rectifiers sounded like they exploded and there was leakage. The part number is D5SBA60 silicon bridge rectifier. I was reading online about the cause of it faling and there was 2 reasons. If the fuse did not blow, then I have an open. And if it did blow, then I have a shorted rectifier. The fuse did not open, so does that mean I still have an open in my circuit? What would I have to inspect before replacing the bridge rectifiers? The only thing I could think of is maybe a bad solder joint or could it have been a bad capacitor that leads to that speaker that caused this reaction?

Here is what I changed in blue circle, but the bridge rectifier is not near here.
[image]

Here is what I have found, I looked at pin 28 on IC501 (input volume selector) and it looked a bit black and I cleaned with alcohol and this appeared suspicious to me

[image]

So now the question is: Is the IC 501 the problem or before it or is resoldering pin for clean connection the solution? This is the most obvious problem I found so could this have been the cause? I checked on the schematics on page 86:
[image]

And here is what is going to INSBL2: 
[image]

Schematics manual: http://www.mediafire.com/file/438o6iwkvfjlacy/Pioneer-VSX-1017TXV-K-Service-Manual.pdf/file
 I forced reset after putting bridge rectifiers and using correct resistor and it turned on, but no volume on speakers. Faulty IC501 (input volume selector)? The reason why the Pioneer system turned on and did not shut down is because I had some sound card loose, the first one I seated correctly was CN501, I turned it on and turned on a few seconds and turned off into protected mode.

Update: I do not have continuity from IC781 pin 1 to C789 positive side, but do have continuity to R797. Is this bad? Here I tested bridge rectifiers, are these good readings? https://youtu.be/GLbh0ko8Fzo
[image]

Comment: Wayyy to little information and repair of consumer electronics without extensive knowledge of the operation is off topic here.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to keep question as simple as possible.

Comment: "Blow up" is imprecise. Was there an explosion?

Comment: The bridge rectifiers sounded like it exploded and smoked came out and the bridge rectifiers were leaking.

Comment: Op ***involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired***. The close reason is ***NOT*** a synonym for "if you don't know how to fix it, don't ask." Voting to reopen.

Comment: Should I post schematics manual?

Comment: the br would overheat if you drew too much current from it, and nothing draws more current than a short. the problem lies downstream

Comment: Schematic! Much better.

Comment: @dandavis Perhaps a bigger resistor allowed more current to pass through, when there was still a short somewhere?

Comment: I updated the description, pin 28 was blackish color, I cleaned it and added solder to the pin to make sure it has good connection. To me this appears to be sort of like an open circuit. I did replace the cap that goes to the pin 28, but I do not believe that it was bad, I just wanted to make sure its new.

Comment: I will be replacing the 2 bridge rectifiers soon, I resoldered pin 28 and replaced electrolytic capacitor that goes to that pin.

Comment: Ok, so I put everything back together and the first time I plug in to AC something clicked and disconnected quickly, connected back and turned on successfully for a couple seconds, but then turned back off into protected mode. I don't know what to do now.

Comment: I usually try to inject the lowest voltage into its rail first, check for heat blooms on thermal camera/feel with finger/freeze the entire board and check where it starts to melt and if nothing, move on to the next higher voltage rail and repeat. My old tutor had the opposite approach, apply full DC voltage with no current limit and observe what pops or catches fire.

Comment: @winny I tried applying voltage to pin 19 on CN501 and set it to at least 2 amps and no amps was loaded on that line. I checked for voltage on pin 21 IC701 and .5 - 1 voltage there and turns off. I do not see voltage going to that chip either though. Right now, I do not know what else to check

Comment: Also, I figured out something important, the exclamation signs on the schematics indicates that it has to be the same type and specification ratings. So, I wonder if something else could have reacted to this? I will probably have to look more in depth in the protection area.

Comment: Where are the bridge rectifiers?

Comment: @winny on page 172, there is D3301 and D3302. Also on page 112, it should say D5SBA60 and not D5SBA20.

Comment: They all fail at once when you plug it in?

Comment: To be honest, its hard to tell, what exactly happened. When I forced reset it the first time, I heard a loud pop and saw smoke come out and I thought it was a fuse but it wasn't and I inspect it carefully and saw silicon leak out of the bridge rectifiers. I think I have an open somewhere.

Comment: Ok so I test in diode mode and ohms mode and compare it to a good one and the readings are just about the same. So possibly still good? I posted video in ohms but did not show diode mode in video.

Comment: Ok, I dont know how I finally got my amplifier to stop restarting but it remained on for some reason. I tested each speaker channel with radio antenna connected and it just makes distortion noise.  So I thought maybe is not sending good audio signal from antenna and I pushed the connector on CN601 near an audio codec chip? And the problem reoccured, it keeps turning on and off. It still restart after disconnecting CN601 though, faulty audio chip?